# How to use a table function outputting 2 columns in an update statement

Tags: t-sql

Pseudocode:

```
Get all projects
Use a table function to get all related parts, which uses project id as input and returns 0..* part ids
Copy a value from project to all found part ids
```

Datamodel:

Table `projects` consists of fields `pj_id` and `pj_desc`

Table `parts` consists of fields `pj_desc_copy` and `prt_id`

There's a function `LookupRelationShips(string)` that outputs multiple columns (`rel_type` and `rel_id`, where if `rel_type` = 2, `rel_id` would be a `prt_id`

My best attempt is this, but it won't let me use the output of the subselect:

```
UPDATE parts
SET pj_desc_copy = rel.pj_desc
from parts prt
INNER JOIN
(select (select rel_type, rel_id, pj.pj_desc
        from LookupRelationShips(pj.pj_id)
        where rel_type = 2)
from projects pj) as rel 
ON rel.rel_id = prt.prt_id
```

Use case/restrictions:
This is a one-time statement to update all current parts. From this point onwards project CRUD will result in syncing parts, but using the application to bulk update previous projects is less than ideal (built-in timeouts, lots of overhead, large dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE parts
SET    pj_desc_copy = pj.pj_desc
FROM   projects pj
       CROSS APPLY LookupRelationShips(pj.pj_id) rel
       RIGHT JOIN parts prt on rel.rel_id = prt.prt_id
WHERE  rel.rel_type = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should be as follow. You can use `CROSS APPLY()` on the function

```
UPDATE prt
SET    pj_desc_copy = rel.pj_desc
FROM   parts prt
       INNER JOIN projects pj ON pj.rel_id = prt.prt_id
       CROSS APPLY LookupRelationShips(pj.pj_id) rel
WHERE  rel.rel_type = 2
```